# Line Breaks In CSS Source Map

Tags: css, google-chrome, less

I have some LESS which is formatted with spaces between the selectors, and braces on a new line.

```
body {
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    font-family:Verdana;
}

header
{
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.7);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100; 
}

#companyLogo
{
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    margin-left:10px; 
}
```

When you view the less through the chrome debugger, it comes through with different spacing, which throws the line numbers way off.

```
body {
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
header {
  background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.7);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
#companyLogo {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

This is the Gruntfile.js i'm using to build the less

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            less: {
                files: ["css/*.less"],
                tasks: ["less"],
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            }
        },
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    //sourceMapFileInline: true,
                    sourceMapBasepath: "css/",
                    sourceMapURL: "style.css.map",
                    sourceMapFilename: "css/style.css.map"
                },
                files: {
                    "css/style.css": "css/style.less"
                }
            },
            compressed:
            {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    //sourceMapFileInline: true,
                    compress: true,
                    sourceMapBasepath: "css/",
                    sourceMapURL: "style.min.css.map",
                    sourceMapFilename: "css/style.min.css.map"
                },
                files: {
                    "css/style.min.css": "css/style.less"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // The following line loads the grunt plugins.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
};
```

Is there any way around this?

It sucks having to do a find on the selector instead of going straight to a line when working in the css.

Comment: @humble.rumble Which setting is it you're thinking of?

Comment: Detect indentation sounds promissing. I'll check in the morning.

Comment: @humble.rumble toggling the detect indentation setting doesn't appear to make a difference

Comment: @humble.rumble show whitespace just displays spaces in the editor as far as I can tell.

Comment: @humble.rumble Weird. Maybe it's something in my css that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm going with for now is to format the less to match what chrome expects with opening braces on the same line as the selector.